# Error 3464 Data type mismatch in criteria expression (Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access database with this code:

```
Sub PonerNRefsProveedores()
 
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * from nrefs"
 
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql)
DoCmd.RunSQL "update proveedores set nrefs=0"
While Not rst.EOF
    DoCmd.RunSQL "update proveedores set nrefs=" & CDbl(rst!cuantos) & " where idproveedor='" & rst!Proveedor & "'"
 
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend
    rst.Close
 
 
End Sub
```

Im getting an error 3464 and I dont really know where is the problem.

The debug stops in `Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql)` :

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uggFD.png)

but in another PC is working properly (with the same code).

I have checked references and they look ok too:

[References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFFkk.png)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `nrefs` is a table name?  In the following SQL it looks like it's a field name...

Answer (score -1):

SQL statements always ends with a ";". This is missing in your SQL strings.

Comment: The semicolon is optional.